# Using only this in controller get $emit in Angular

Tags: angularjs, scope, controller, this, emit

Can we use only `this` in controllers, without `$scope`?

In some cases of course yes, i know... But...

If we need `$emit`, `$broadcast` and some other angular features, which we can find only in scope? Can we get it in this may be, or some other ways to get it?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codelord.net/2015/11/11/angular-controlleras-when-should-you-use-scope/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there are some special cases like $emit etc which you have to use $scope and can't use this.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a controller in this format :

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
     //controller code here
}]);
```

the function that you are passing is basically a **constructor for the controller object**

so when you write a code like this :

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
         this.myObject = { key : value};
    }]);
```

you are basically making `myObject` a property of the `myController` object

Controllers are basically used in angular.js to fascillitate communication between your view( which are handled by directives ) and services( which take care of the buisness logic )

To enable that you can use the dependency injection angular provides and insert the `$scope` object into your controller as shown above

when you instantiate a controller using `ng-controller="myController"` a new scope object is created to be used with your controller object. the `$scope` object that you have passed as an argument to the constructor function of the controller has the newly created scope.

Here is an excerpt from angular documentation :

The properties contain the view model (the model that will be presented by the view). All the $scope properties will be available to the template at the point in the DOM where the Controller is registered.

so basically whatever properties **you attach to the $scope object only will be avalaible to be manipulated in DOM**

any property you attach to `this` wont be available in the DOM. for example :

```
this is you angular configuration :

angular.module('myModule').controller('myController',['$scope',function($scope){
             $scope.name = 'kiran'
             this.message = 'hello world';
        }]); 
This is your html :

<p>{{name}}</p>
```

Output will be : kiran.

if you had tried : `<p>{{message}}</p>` instead it will throw an error.

**only the scope object** contains properties like  $$watchers which is a list of all the variables that are watched on the current scope, $watch API,$on API for event handling and so on.

so you cannot use this to leverage those properties.Hope this clears stuff up.